# How can I monitor network traffic of an internally connected device to my router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openwrt

I have the TP-LINK TL-WR1043ND router with OpenWRT 14.07 Barrier Breaker installed.

I would like to know how often and for how long my 3-year-old kid is watching YouTube through his Samsung tablet, while I am not at home. I need to know whether the babysitter is giving him the tablet all day long, or just occasionally when he is eating, for example.

So at the end I would like to have historical statistics for when the device was actively using the internet (not some background traffic). Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I had such router and to the best of my knowledge you have a Parental control option on your router if you're comfortable with techy stuff configuring MAC addresses.
I do not know how you could monitor per client with your router.
I think your firmware does not allow this option.  (but I might be mistaken)
If you don't mind receiving statistics for all your connected clients, you could install [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/).